# Tomcat + hibernate = no persistent classes found for query class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I'm developing a web app and deploying it on Tomcat 7.0. My app uses a MySQL database. I've already configured connection between app and database and wanted to add Hibernate 5.2.5 support. I can **communicate with database via Hibernate console** with configuration below, and **it works when I use it in non-web app**. The problem is only when I deploy it on server. I get warning

```
no persistent classes found for query class: from entities.UserH
```

and then 500 server error caused by it.

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames =     {"id"})})
public class UserH {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String surname;

    /* getters and setters*/
}
```

My hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection properties - Driver, URL, user, password -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web-database</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
        <mapping class="entities.UserH"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Method that should get users:

```
public List<UserH> getAllUsers() {

    try (Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionAnnotationFactory().getCurrentSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query<UserH> usersQuery = session.createQuery("from entities.UserH", UserH.class);
        List<UserH> usersList = usersQuery.getResultList();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return usersList;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned - it works ok with normal app, but not with Tomcat. I added all available elements to web artifacts, but it didn't help. I even tried to add JPA support with `persistance.xml`, but still with no luck.

What else could be the problem?

edit: My HibernateUtils class:

```
public class HibernateUtils {
    private static SessionFactory sessionAnnotationFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionAnnotationFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionAnnotationFactory() {
        if (sessionAnnotationFactory == null) 
            sessionAnnotationFactory = buildSessionAnnotationFactory();
        return sessionAnnotationFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your `HibernateUtils` class code.

Comment: @Naros, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not a proper answer fot my question, but this is what actually worked for me. I replaced hibernate with JPA configuration + hibernate.

So instead of using hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml + Session I used persistance.xml + EntityManager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entities.UserH</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web-database"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="Admin"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password2@"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

getEntityManager:

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit")
            .createEntityManager();

    return entityManager;
}
```

getAllUsers:

```
public List<UserH> getAllUsers() {

    EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtils.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    TypedQuery<UserH> usersQuery = entityManager.createQuery("from UserH ", UserH.class);
    List<UserH> usersList = usersQuery.getResultList();
    transaction.commit();
    entityManager.close();

    return usersList;
}
```

However, I still don't understand why this configurations works while hibernate alone didn't. Any comments/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change your query to reference only the class name:

```
session.createQuery( "FROM UserH", UserH.class )
```

The only time the package is important would be when you're defining entities as inner classes.

For those cases, you'd need to use the full class name, `com.c.SomeOutterClass$MyEntity`.  Another alternative is to change the `@Entity` annotation so that it includes the name attribute so you explicitly name your entity class:

```
public class SomeOutterClass {
  @Entity(name = "MyEntity")
  public static class MyEntity {

  }
}
```

Comment: My class is not an inner class. When I remove the package part from query I get error: `QuerySyntaxException: UserH is not mapped [from UserH]`. It happens even if I specify the name in `@Entity` annotation.